# Override config map file in helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We have helm charts to deploy our application. We use a `configuration.json` file for application properties and load them to config map. But users typically use their own configuration file.

Default configuration.json file is packaged inside helm charts under data directoty. This file is read as

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: app-config
data:
{{ (.Files.Glob .Values.appConfigFile).AsConfig | indent 4}}
```

And in values

```
appConfigFile: data/configuration.json
```

If users install our charts directly from repository how can this configuration file be overriden? doing `--set appConfigFile=/path/to/custom.json` doen't populate config map.

If charts are untarred to a directory they can add the custom configuration file into charts directory and give the configuration file using `--set appConfigFile=customData/custom.json` works

Can file overrides be achieved when charts are deployed from repository directly?

Answer (score 13):

Adding custom configuration to a values file and execute `helm install` using `-f` flag is a solution.

customValues.yaml

```
overrideConfig: true
customConfig:{
//Add your custom json here as variable value
}
```

Config map yaml

```
#If custom values file passed then overrideConfig variable will be set. 
#So load configmap from customConfig variable
{{ if .Values.overrideConfig}}
    app-config.json : |-
      {{ toJson .Values.customConfig }}
{{ else }}
# Else load from the default configuration available in charts.
{{ (.Files.Glob .Values.appConfigFile).AsConfig indent 4 }}
{{ end }}
```

If custom configuration is needed

```
helm install -f customValues.yaml repo/chartName
```

Not sure if this is the perfect solution, but ended up taking this route.

Comment: This solution cannot override subchart's ConfigMap by parent chart's one with config. files. You have to paste whole content in config. files as JSON string to `customValues.yaml`.

Comment: This is a very nice solution for cases where you need to override the entire section in a configuration.